# Segregation Of Columns based on datatype

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if there was any way to segregate columns based on data-type in SQL? Suppose there is a table consisting of 4 columns, two of numerical type and other 2 of character type.
E.g:- create table student
(fname varchar2(20)
sname varchar2(20)
sid number,
ssn number);

I want to copy fname and sname into a separate table and sid and ssn into another table using some commands.

I tried this in MySQL but it returns an error multiple rows selected

```
select <list_of_column_names>
from <table_name>
where<condition>

select<name1>
from student
where type1 like %char%
```

Comment: You could use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-select.html) or [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html), but *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you store social security numbers as a *NUMBER* and not as a string.  This is an identifier, and it is perfectly valid (in the United States at least) for the "number" to start with a zero.  And the leading zero is important.

Comment: Thanks to both eggyal and gordon for your respective pointers. I actually require it for an assignment.